# Andrioid # of supported OpenSL AudioBuffers in Marshmallow (API23)

Tags: audio, android-ndk, opensl

I have an Android app which uses OpenSL ES for audio.   It runs correctly in API17 through API 22.  While developing the app, I read somewhere that although OpenSL supports up to 32 objects (platform dependent), Android supports only 11.  And so, I designed the app accordingly.

For example I create multiple buffer objects in JNI

```
// buffer queue player interfaces
// FIRST BUFFER
static SLObjectItf buffer_obj_mainBeat_1 = NULL;
static SLPlayItf buffer_itf_mainBeat_1;
static SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf buf_q_mainBeat_1;
// SECOND BUFFER
static SLObjectItf buffer_obj_mainBeat_2 = NULL;
static SLPlayItf buffer_itf_mainBeat_2;      
static SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf buf_q_mainBeat_2;
// THIRD BUFFER
static SLObjectItf buffer_obj_mainBeat_3 = NULL;
static SLPlayItf buffer_itf_mainBeat_3;
static SLAndroidSimpleBufferQueueItf buf_q_mainBeat_3;
```

Then, I also define the required player interfaces etc...

In the Java code I play each of the defined objects sequentially in loop:

```
public void playMainBeat {
  switch (mainBeat_buf_counter) {
     case 1:
       setPlayStateMainBeat1(true);    // play this sound
       setPlayStateMainBeat2(false);   // stop next bufQ if not done and rewind
       mainBeat_buf_counter = 2;
       break;
     case 2:
       setPlayStateMainBeat2(true);
       setPlayStateMainBeat3(false);
       mainBeat_buf_counter = 3;
       break;
     case 3:
       setPlayStateMainBeat3(true);
       setPlayStateMainBeat1(false);
       mainBeat_buf_counter = 1;
       break;
  }
}
```

Each of the sound samples that I am playing are about 300 milliseconds.  I don't want to stop one sound while playing the next as I loop through the sequence.  Notice that I stop the 1st sound after starting the 3rd. Then the loop starts at the top again.  The loop in the Java code looks something like the following code:

```
mainBeat_buf_counter = 1; // initialize counter
while (hasStarted){
  playMainBeat();
  try {
    Thread.sleep(soundInterval);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {; }
}
```

This all works great until API23 (Marshmallow).  Marshmallow will not play all the buffers.  It simply fails to play.  Sounds are absent in a regular pattern.

I cannot find any documentation regarding the number of objects supported by Android for OpenSL ES.  But, if I reduce the number of objects to 7 it does not skip sounds.  However, the reduced number of buffers is not adequate for my application.  I suspect that the number of supported objects was reduced from 11 objects to 7 objects at API23.

Can anyone confirm the number of objects supported in Android?  Or, maybe I am going about this all wrong and there is a better way?

Thanks,

Comment: I received an update for Android studio today which included API-24. All of the audio problems that I am experiencing with API-23 went away with API-24. I guess I have to conclude that my app is okay but Marshmallow got a little overdone in the campfire - so my app will never run on API-23.

Comment: This bug was acknowledged by Don Turner & Phil Burk in their talk [What's New In Android Audio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dAyeEN21FbM#t=7m3s). According to them It is fixed in Nougat.

Comment: I recently found that there is a Marshmallow release 6.0.1 which fixes this problem.
BUT - It appears that the bug reappears in  Nougat release API25

see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=232569 for additional details

Comment: API25 = Nougat 7.1.1